# Is is possible to use library with C# 9 Records in .NET Framework 4.x

Tags: .net, c#-9.0

Is there a way to create library with records and then use it in *legacy* .NET Framework 4.x application?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, although this is not officially supported.

Firstly you have to set the LangVersion to 9, which you can do by manually editing the csproj, e.g.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You then have to add the following file to your library:

```cs
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices { internal class IsExternalInit { } }
```

After that you should be able to declare and use records as normal in your library.